# How to interpret result of manipulation of $Z^n-X^n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, natural-numbers

Start from eq. (1)  $Z^n-X^n=Y^n$, where $n, X, Y$ and $Z$ and are positive integers $X<Y<Z$. Replace $Z = X + B$, and remember eq. (2) $$X=Z-B$$
$B$ is also a positive integer. Then
$$(X+B)^2Z^{n-2}-X^2X^{n-2}=Y^n.$$
Solve $X^2$:
$$X^2=\frac{Y^n}{Z^{n-2}-X^{n-2}} - \frac{B(X+Z)Z^{n-2}}{Z^{n-2}-X^{n-2}}.$$
Divide by $X$:
$$X = \frac{Y^n}{(\frac{X}{Z})Z^{n-1}-X^{n-1}} - \frac{BZ^{n-1}\frac{Z+X}{Z}}{(\frac{X}{Z})Z^{n-1}-X^{n-1}}.$$
Replace $\frac{X}{Z} = r$, $0<r<1$, and the result is eq. (3):$$X=\frac{Z(1-r^n)-B(1+r)}{r-r^{n-1}}$$
Now, this result does not seem to fit with the original assumption $X=Z-B$. Namely, according to the result $X$ is $Z-B$ only if the ratio $r$ is zero (which it cannot) in numerator but that would also cause the denominator to be zero. Please let me know how to interpret this (I am not a mathematician so I may sometimes be easily confusing/confused).

Comment: Another thing you can note is that due to Fermat's Last Theorem, n cannot be larger than 2.

Comment: "*the result $X$ is $Z−B$ only if the ratio r is zero*" $\;-\;$ Why? $\;$ "*how to interpret this*" $\;-\;$ That's hard to guess. You just wrote some formulas without any explanation of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Remembering that $B = Z - X = Z(1 - r),$
a simpler way to derive your final equation is

\begin{align}
X = rZ &= \frac{r^2 - r^n}{r - r^{n-1}} Z \\
&= \frac{(1 - r^n) - (1 - r^2)}{r - r^{n-1}} Z \\
&= \frac{Z(1 - r^n) - Z(1 - r)(1 + r)}{r - r^{n-1}} \\
&= \frac{Z(1 - r^n) - B(1 + r)}{r - r^{n-1}}.
\end{align}

So the final equation indeed is something of the form $\frac{uZ - vB}{w}$,
but you get it by slicing and dicing your terms (or whatever you want to call it; in any case it's a lot of algebraic manipulation).
The only role of $X = Z - B$ is in the step $Z(1 - r) \to B.$

Similarly, we can confirm that
$$ 3 = \frac{8\cdot 11 - 5\cdot 14}{6}, $$
where there is no sensible way of canceling the $6$ with either the $11$ or the $14$ in order to derive the equation $3 = 8 - 5$,
but nevertheless it is true that $3 = 8 - 5$.

---

As a side note, if $n = 2$ then $r^{n-1} = r,$ so anything with $r - r^{n-1}$ in the denominator is undefined.
Really this should be no surprise, since then $n - 2 = 0$,
implying that $X^{n-2} = Z^{n-2} = 1$ and
$Z^{n-2} - X^{n-2} = 0,$
so dividing by $Z^{n-2} - X^{n-2}$ is not legitimate.

Since it has already been observed that $n \leq 2$ by Fermat's Last Theorem,
it follows that the only positive integer value of $n$ for which
$Z^{n-2} - X^{n-2} \neq 0$ is $n = 1.$
In that case your final equation comes out to

$$ X = \frac{Z(1 - r) - B(1 + r)}{r - 1} = \frac{B(1 + r) - Z(1 - r)}{1 - r}
 = B\frac{1 + r}{1 - r} - Z, $$

which looks even worse at first glance ("wrong signs" on the $B$ and $Z$ terms),
but note that

$$ B\frac{1 + r}{1 - r} = B + \frac{2rB}{1 - r}
 = B + \frac{2rZ(1-r)}{1 - r} = B + 2X. $$

And it makes perfect sense that $X = 2X - (Z - B).$

---

So what's **really** going on here?

It is a fact that if you have any two integers $P$ and $Q$, you can choose any integer multiple of $\gcd(P,Q)$ that you like, and there will be a linear combination $uP + vQ$, where $u$ and $v$ are integers, that comes out to that multiple of $\gcd(P,Q)$.
Moreover, there are infinitely many such linear combinations, because if
$$ uP + vQ = k \gcd(P,Q) $$
then
$$ u'P + v'Q = k \gcd(P,Q) $$
where $u' = u + Q/\gcd(P,Q)$ and $v' = v - P/\gcd(P,Q)$.
This also works if $u' = u - Q/\gcd(P,Q)$ and $v' = v + P/\gcd(P,Q)$,
and it's a simple consequence of the fact that $QP - PQ = 0.$

This works as well for rational multiples of $\gcd(P,Q)$ where
$u$ and $v$ are rational.

Applying this to your equations, let $P = Z$ and let $Q = B.$
Then $X = Z - B$ is a rational multiple of $\gcd(P,Q)$.
So is $X(r - r^{n-1})$. Obviously we can make this multiple of $\gcd(P,Q)$
by scaling the linear combination $Z - B$:
$$ X(r - r^{n-1}) = Z(r - r^{n-1}) - B(r - r^{n-1}). $$
That is, we have the linear combination $uP + vQ$ where
$u = r - r^{n-1}$ and $v = r^{n-1} - r.$
But that is only one of the infinitely many possible linear combinations of $Z$ and $B$ with the same total.
By increasing $u$ by a suitable amount and reducing $v$ by a suitable amount
we can obtain
$$ X(r - r^{n-1}) = Z(1 - r^n) - B(1 + r). $$
In the case where $r \neq r^{n-1}$ you can divide through by
$r - r^{n-1}$ and obtain your Equation $(3)$.

What does this have to do with the equation $Y^n = X^n + Z^n$?
Not much.
It is all simply a consequence of the assumption that $X$ and $Z$ are integers.
Notice that the only appearance of $Y$ in any of your equations is in the form $Y^n,$ and except for the initial assertion that $Y$ is an integer you never again rely on the fact that $Y$ is an integer;
after a while you replace $Y^n$ by $Z^n - X^n$ and then it's gone.
So really all of these algebraic manipulations are just about the integers $Z,$ $X,$ and $B,$ and as we see here there is nothing at all remarkable about the fact that we're able to recombine $Z$ and $B$ in a linear combination that is not just $Z - B$ and get the total $X$ again.
It's just a simple consequence of the integer equation $X = Z - B.$

In particular, none of this tells us anything about the solutions to
$Y^n = Z^n - X^n.$
It does not in any way contradict the hypothesis that an integer solution to this equation exists when $n = 3$ or when $n$ is any larger integer.
And that's a good thing, because if there **were** a contradiction,
what would it say about the case where $n = 1$?

Of course we still know what we know about the integer solutions of
$Y^n = Z^n - X^n,$ thanks to some more advanced mathematics.
All of the arithmetic gymnastics in the question and in this answer do not contradict Andrew Wiles's work; by the same token, they do not lead to a simpler demonstration of Fermat's Last Theorem either.

Comment: Equation (1) is the starting point. Equation (2) is a general assumption that does not limit the original equation (1). Then some simple and legimate manipulation is performed. And the result is equation (3), which seems to be contradictory to equation (2). I do not find that slicing and dicing. For n = 1, eq. (3) makes indeed sense. For n = 2, eq. (3) cannot be used. And for  n > 2, X cannot be Z - B although eq. (2) does not limit the original eq. (1). => Simple sign that eq. (1) is not solvable when n > 2, or is it?

Comment: @David Your "*simple and legitimate manipulation*" does not appear to use the premise that $X,Y,Z$ are positive integers anywhere. The same steps would then "prove" that $Z^n-X^n=Y^n$ has no solutions in real (or complex) numbers, but that's very obviously false.

Comment: Note that I never said any of the manipulations in the question was illegitimate (except possibly neglecting to specify that $n \neq 2$ when dividing by $r - r^{n-1}$). You certainly can do these operations. I'm just saying that the results of all of these manipulations don't tell us anything about the original problem $Y^n = Z^n - X^n.$

Comment: @xdiv You're right, none of this has anything to do with the existence or non-existence of solutions to the original problem. It's completely irrelevant. That's my point. (The supposed relevance to FLT is only asserted in the question, not in my answer.)